# Trial Divison Algorithm in Maple

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, maple

I have the following code for Trial Divison Algorithm in Maple:

```
TrialDivision := proc( n :: integer )
    if n <= 1 then
            false
    elif n = 2 then
            true
    elif type( n, 'even' ) then
            false
    else
            for local i from 3 by 2 while i * i <= n do
                if irem( n,i) = 0 then
                        return false
                end if
            end do;
            true
     end if
end proc:
```

which I got from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Primality_by_trial_division#MATLAB. But when I try to run it, it is giving me the following error: Error, unexpected `local` declaration in procedure body.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This help page contains useful information on Maple proc's and even inner proc's http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/lexical  see the last example in the page, it is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing local declarations throughout the procedure body is a somewhat recent addition to the Maple language.

You could change it to this, say.

```
TrialDivision := proc( n :: integer )
    local i;
    if n <= 1 then
            false
    elif n = 2 then
            true
    elif type( n, 'even' ) then
        false
    else
            for i from 3 by 2 while i * i <= n do
                if irem( n,i) = 0 then
                        return false
                end if
            end do;
            true
     end if
end proc:
```